# How do I use a column from another query in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

The first query contains all the boxes with division as null, and the second contains folders. However, I want only the folders that have `DPERMCONTAINER` attribute equal the `DID` resulted in the first query. I would like to make only 1 query that produces the desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID) DID,
                TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER) PERMCONTAINER,
                S.DBARCODE,
                S.DDOCTITLE,
                S.XCOMMENTS,
                SRM.XCATEGORYID,
                S.XDIVISION,
                S.DMEDIATYPE
FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S
LEFT JOIN PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMSRM SRM ON S.DID = SRM.DID
WHERE S.XDIVISION IS NULL
    AND UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) = 'BOX';

SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID) DID,
                TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER) PERMCONTAINER,
                S.DBARCODE,
                S.DDOCTITLE,
                S.XCOMMENTS,
                SRM.XCATEGORYID,
                S.XDIVISION,
                S.DMEDIATYPE
FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S
LEFT JOIN PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMSRM SRM ON S.DID = SRM.DID
WHERE UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) = 'FOLDER';
```

Comment: If you could some sample data and expected output based on that, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I want a list of boxes that matches the criteria and only the folders associated to those boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add IN() statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID) DID, TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER) PERMCONTAINER, S.DBARCODE, 
S.DDOCTITLE, S.XCOMMENTS, SRM.XCATEGORYID, S.XDIVISION, S.DMEDIATYPE
FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
LEFT JOIN PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMSRM SRM ON S.DID = SRM.DID
WHERE UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) ='FOLDER'
  AND  TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER)  in(SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID) 
                                     FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S 
                                     LEFT JOIN PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMSRM SRM ON S.DID = SRM.DID 
                                     WHERE S.XDIVISION IS NULL AND UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) ='BOX');
```

Comment: I got an error "too many values". Also will this compare the S.DPERMCONTAINER in the 2nd query to the S.DID in the 1st query? Because I only want the folder output of the boxes listed from the 1st query.

Comment: I tried this and it's giving me the "missing expression" error instead of producing a list of folders.

`SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID) DID, TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER) PERMCONTAINER, S.DBARCODE, S.DDOCTITLE, S.XCOMMENTS, SRM.XCATEGORYID, S.XDIVISION, S.DMEDIATYPE
FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S LEFT JOIN PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMSRM SRM ON S.DID = SRM.DID
WHERE UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) ='FOLDER' 
AND TO_CHAR(S.DPERMCONTAINER) IN (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(S.DID),
FROM PRD64_URMSERVER.EXTITEMS S
WHERE S.XDIVISION IS NULL AND UPPER(S.DMEDIATYPE) ='BOX');`

Comment: oops, I left a comma where it shouldn't be. I tried it and it produced a list of folders. I limited it to 10 rows `ROWNUM <=10` otherwise it might be something like 1.3 million rows. Now I'm going to UNION that with just boxes to see if it all matches up the way it should. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'll appreciate an approval then.. And also, the select you posted in the comments seems wrong! notice that inside the IN() there is no left join where there should be(look at my solution) so validate you are using the correct query. @Charles

Comment: I wasn't sure if the `in()` needed to have that left join. Since the only purpose for the left join was for `srm.xcategoryid` which was on another table. Since the `in()` only used `s.did, s.xdivision, and s.dmediatype` maybe I didn't need it?

Comment: I'm not sure either, I don't know the logic behind all this queries.. so you'll have to try with and without and see if its the same. @Charles